# asciidoc: How to operate mathematically with page-number et al?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

## Setup

I export a PDF with the following footer:

```
footer:
  height: 0.75in
  line_height: 1
  recto_content:
    right: '{page-number}/{page-count}'
```

## Question:

I want to increase both `page-number` and `page-count` by `page-offset`.

## What I've tried so far:

I found [a possibly related discussion](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1016) and tried stuff like

```
{page-offset} // works, so page-offset is known here

{calc:page-number + page-offset} // might be not working due to "-" vs. "+", so:

{calc:{page-number} + {page-offset}} // just replaces vars: "{calc:1 + 42}"

:pagenum: calc:[{page-number} + {page-offset}]
recto_content:
  right: '{pagenum}' // no output at all
```

So I guess I need to implement `calc` before I can use it, but how do I do so? I found [a second possibly related thread](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/1631#issuecomment-608983973), but where would I put such a macro?

## UPDATE:

I found the ["Math Expressions & Functions"-section](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc#math-expressions--functions), which seems to work with variables only. So I tried to convert `page-number` and `page-offset` into variables before summing them up:

```
footer:
  foo:
    a: '{page-number}'
    b: '{page-offset}'
    bar: $footer_foo_a + $footer_foo_b
  height: 0.75in
  line_height: 1
  recto_content:
    right: $footer_foo_bar
```

But they are treated as the Strings they are; rendered output is "1 + 42"...

**So basically this question is: How to operate mathematically with `page-number` and/or how to convert it into a number?**

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/1728) I guess I'll have to wait for. It addresses page numbering and how to configure it

Comment: Have you tried `bar: $page-number + $page-offset`? I don't use asciidoctor-pdf, so I'm only speculating.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work as they are no variable (yet): `WARNING: unknown variable reference in PDF theme: $page` (because of the `-`), and using `$page_number` (because `-` and `_` are interchangeable here) gives me `WARNING: unknown variable reference in PDF theme: $page_number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/1728#issuecomment-679296159) I added an inline macro. It's kind of well documented how to register macros (and/or extensions, for that matter), but not exactly *where* to register them. So here we go:

Include the extension file in `build.gradle`, pass the offset if required:

```
asciidoctor {
  attributes 'some-x': 'x',
        'some-y': 'y',
        'page-offset': System.getProperty('pageOffset', '0')

  requires = ['./src/docs/asciidoc/lib/pagenum-inline-macro.rb']

  // ...
}
```

in `src/docs/asciidoc/lib/pagenum-inline-macro.rb` the extension is registered:

```
RUBY_ENGINE == 'opal' ? (require 'pagenum-inline-macro/extension') : (require_relative 'pagenum-inline-macro/extension')

Asciidoctor::Extensions.register do
  if @document.basebackend? 'html'
    inline_macro PagenumInlineMacro
  end
end
```

and, last but nor least, the actual functionality is in `src/docs/asciidoc/lib/pagenum-inline-macro/extension.rb`:

```
require 'asciidoctor/extensions' unless RUBY_ENGINE == 'opal'

include Asciidoctor

class PagenumInlineMacro < Extensions::InlineMacroProcessor
  use_dsl
  named :pagenum

  def process parent, target, attributes
    doc = parent.document
    page_offset = (doc.attr 'page-offset', 0).to_i
    page_num = (doc.attr 'page-number', 0).to_i + page_offset
    page_total = (doc.attr 'page-count', 0).to_i + page_offset
    %(#{page_num}/#{page_total})
  end
end
```

I use it in my `theme.yml`:

```
footer:
  height: 0.75in
  columns: <25% =50% >25%
  recto:
    right:
      content: pagenum:[][]
```

Didn't find a more elegant solution for `[][]`, but I'm ok with that.